# Recent Post Added To Menu Shows Ghost Post With No Title

Tags: posts

When I go to Appearance > Menu and add a selected category to my Menu, then when I visit the page it shows in the recent post sidebar a few (no title) post. I'm not sure why these are showing up, I can't find these post it shows me to even delete them. Is there a way I can stop this without having to redo my website?

Here is where you can see on the website, on the right side sidebar under the recent post. However, if you click Home you see the recent post sidebar and it's working??

[MY Website Problem Page](https://www.elitexcoders.com/category/realm-swift/)

I've also included a screenshot[image: Screen Shot Of How Menu Is Setup] of this.